# Cart rule free shipping on subtotal after discount magento 2

Tags: magento2, discount, free-shipping

I am working on Magento 2.2.5. I have one cart rule that gives free shipping if the subtotal is equal to or greater then $50.

It is working well, but if the user gets any discount from a coupon or any other discount then it is not working properly as subtotal is not considering discount amount.

If user purchases $55 products then he/she will get the free shipping in the checkout page. But when he uses the coupon that gives 10%($5.5) discount then the amount will be $49.5 then also the free shipping is applying.

So anyway to add this rule on subtotal including discounted amount?

Or do I need to change any code for cart rule?

I read many solutions from the stack and tried but with no luck.

Some of are of Magento 1 but I am using Magento 2.2.5

Comment: you can set the condition on **subtotal** if its not work try action on **price in cart**  in cart rule

Comment: Currently the rule is on subtotal. if subtotal is equal or greater then $50 then free shipping will apply/

Comment: Ok so try with actions on **price in cart** in cart rule it will solve your issue

Comment: No it is not working by that way also.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: HI @DavidCoder did you get any answer for this question. I am having similar issue, I want to apply on grand total

Answer (score 0):

1. First You need to disable `free shipping` and enable `flat rate`.
2. After that, you need to set the `catalog price rules` for free shipping discount over an order of `50$ or greater`(add appropriate condition there).
   the 
   In above case, your `cart price rule(coupon code)` and `catalog price rule` will work parallel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not using free shipping method of magento. I have created rule for free shipping.

Comment: Flate rate method is already enable

Comment: My free shipping rule is already set with subtotal greater then $50. I am not getting   your 2nd rule.

Comment: Ok got it your case, you have created two coupon code right? one is for free shipping and other one is normal coupon code

Comment: Yes I have created cart rule for free shipping. I am not using magento's free shipping method. I have many other coupon code  rule that can be use in checkout page to get discount

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if your problem is still a thing, but i stumbled upon this a few month ago and found a solution for nearly the same issue, so maybe it helps someone.
For me following this tutorial: https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-custom-sales-rule-condition/ 
 and changing the validation function worked. As in the documentation of AbstractModel 
(https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/class_magento_1_1_quote_1_1_model_1_1_cart_1_1_totals.html) 
 you can call the getSubtotalWithDiscount() function within the model and validate for being greater than 50.

```php
public function validate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
{
    $price = 0;   
    $price = $model->getSubtotalWithDiscount();

    if($price > 50){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I need to update this code?

Comment: @VIPINAROY if you followed the tutorial, you can find the validate function in *YOUR CODE DIRECTORY*/CustomerRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Customer.php . This function returns true or false, so you can modify as you need it

Answer (score 0):

Actually the option Subtotal (excl. Tax) seems to be with discount, when having a look at the dropdown I see this:

```
<option value="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address|base_subtotal_with_discount">Subtotal (Excl. Tax)</option>
```

So the `base_subtotal_with_discount` really seems to mean, that functionality is there in the core, but well hidden by bad translation.

*EDIT*

Actually this does not work :)

Comment: Hi Alex, have you found any solution to this?

Comment: I don't think I did

Answer (score 0):

After some Extensive research, here is the answer (tested on Magento 1.9.2.3): Modify the following file `websitename/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/FreeShipping.php`

Change the following line:

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping()) || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
```

Replace it with the following:

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping()) || ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >= $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
```

The `$request->getPackageValueWithDiscount()` will give you the Grand Total.